# How to speed up multiple filter queries in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a use case where a query needs to come only from a few web sites (I am building some kind of e-commerce search and there are products from different retailer web sites) and those few web sites can be different (actually most of the time it will be different). So I am OR'ing a few sites in the filter something like this:

```
fq=site:"aaa.com"+OR+site:"bbb.com"+OR+site:"ccc.com"+OR+site:"ddd.com"
```

This is too slow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `site` is a text field and the double quotes are making it a phrase query. Make `site` a string field. Then use:

```
fq=site:(aaa.com OR bbb.com OR ccc.com OR ddd.com)
```

If you cannot make `site` a string field, keep a copyField of `site` which is of string type and execute the above query on that field.